# how to detect collisions between SKSpriteNodes in specific locations on the sprite nodes?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to implement functionality of detecting a collision between 2 sprites but only in specific location on those sprites. For instance, if I have a hook and a fish, and the purpose of the game is to catch a fish on a hook, then only the collision between the point of the hook and the mouth or front part (say 10%) of the fish should matter, but not any other collision. 
Is there a simple, built-in way to test for this ? If not, any guidance about how to do it?

I have the following standard code that gets the collision point on the frame, to which I add
     CGPoint p = contact.contactPoint;

where do I go from there?

```
 - (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
 {
     SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

     if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
     {
         firstBody = contact.bodyA;
         secondBody = contact.bodyB;
     }
     else
     {
         firstBody = contact.bodyB;
         secondBody = contact.bodyA;
     }

     if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & hookCategory) != 0 &&
         (secondBody.categoryBitMask & fishCategory) != 0)
     {
         CGPoint p = contact.contactPoint;

         [self caught:(SKSpriteNode *) firstBody.node didCatchFish: (Fish *) secondBody.node];
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contactPoint` represents a point in scene coordinates. You want to convert it to your node (`Fish`) coordinates:

```
Fish *fishNode = (Fish *) secondBody.node;
CGPoint p = [fishNode convertPoint:contact.contactPoint fromNode:self.scene];
```

After that you can check point position, if it belongs to the fish's mouth or whatever:

```
if (p.x < 10.0) {
    [self caught:(SKSpriteNode *) firstBody.node didCatchFish: fishNode];
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thank you, Andrey, that's very helpful. Would you happen to have any pointers for me for where to look for guidance on general collision detection? For some reason I am noticing that the app won't detect a collision until one sprites is at the second sprite's center, as opposed to the very first x-coordinate they intersect at; I have been looking high and low but can't seem to find any explanation for why that happens.

Comment: I know only official Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the physics engine? You could add a sub node (visible or not) of the fish. Set the appropriate masks:

```
mouth.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = MouthMask;
mouth.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = HookMask;
```

The in the `SKPhysicsWorld` delegate method `didBeginContact:` you can test for the relevant conditions for "hook in mouth".

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  NSLog(@"%s\n  %@\n  %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [contact bodyA], [contact bodyB]);
}
```